# Unrestricted codec for creating raster files with interior pyramids files

Tags: raster, imagery

I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to mosaic a collection of images into a file format with performance similar to MrSID or ECW, but without the licensing restrictions that those formats come with. (I believe the .sid limit is 50 mb with the ECW limit is 500 mb).  Unfortunately, the tool that I am working with doesn't recognize external pyramid files (.rrd) or .tif with internal pyramids.

Does that leave me any good options?

Comment: Do you have the option of using a tiled mosaic so you do not go over the size limitations of those formats?

Comment: Also, you say you are looking for a tool but it sounds like you are looking for an image format. Do you have a list of allowable formats?

Comment: I can work with any of the FDO supported formats, so I do have flexibility there.  And, yes, tiling is OK, but performance wise I've found that I'm better off with fewer files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JPEG2000](http://www.jpeg.org/jpeg2000/) could be an option.  Its performance would likely be implementation-specific, so I don't know how it stacks up against MrSID / ECW.

There is an open implementation available from [OpenJPEG](http://www.openjpeg.org/) that might suit your needs..

Comment: I didn't know about OpenJPEG.  I'll take a look today.  Thanks!

Comment: OpenJPEG did it, though it's a little balky for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [FDO Raster Provider](http://trac.osgeo.org/fdo/wiki/FdoGdalNotes) on top of [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/), and gdal itself supports many internal and external pyramids, including geotiff's and .rrd's. So perhaps via that you could utilize them.